# Using edgemodifier Labels in apache airflow API (TaskFlow)

Tags: python, airflow

Is there any way to use `airflow.utils.edgemodifier.Label` when defining DAGs with Apache Airflow's TaskFlow API?

In the [old DAG definition](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html) format you could introduce labels that would be visible in the UI graph view.

But in the [new TaskFlow API format](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html) there does not seem to be a way to include labels, as the DAG is inferred by how objects are passed between tasks.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found it possible to add edge label using the task variables,

```
submit_request = submit_some_request(validate_request['payload'])
request_status = get_request_status(submit_request['request_id'])
submit_request >> Label("request_id") >> request_status
```

Comment: what does the last line of this mean?

Comment: Last line does the same thing as 2nd line but adds an edge label more traditional way. Kind of a workaround since i dont find how otherwise we can add edge label in the task flow way.

Comment: I didn't know it overloaded shift operators; neat!